# Can not find or calculate ampere hour from the data sheet

Tags: current, ampere-hour

Here is the data sheet of a ups:

http://www.ups-service.by/PDF/Technical_Specification_PowerWave_60-500kW_English.pdf

How long for a nominal 500A current drawing load would this utility last?
How can I calculate it?
Couldnt find from the technical datasheet.

Comment: You configure those with the amount of batteries you need.

Comment: Can you give one  example?

Comment: 80 28Ah batteries.

Comment: many thanks. so in my case can i say 80*28/500 = 4.5 so it will last only 4.5 hours? is that right calculation?

Comment: Only if your system is 100% efficient and your power draw keeps dropping together with the battery voltage

Comment: If you're looking at p.17, I think PlasmaHH missed that those 80 batteries are 12V each, arranged 2x40, or 480V * 56Ah. Only recommended below 100kW. At 500A they won't last very long : nominally 0.1 hours, but batteries discharged at the 10C rate won't deliver their full nominal capacity. And unless they are spec'ed for deep discharge you don't want to use their nominal capacity, so this configuration is practically good for something in the region of two minutes. But it'll serve as a starting point for determining the batteries you need.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Im confused. why do they produce 400kw 500kw ups models if they only run 0.1 hours? can the hours be extended?

Comment: Of course it can be extended. See the first comment from @PlasmaHH.

Comment: @user16307, This is the time it takes to start reserving systems. Such as diesel, petrol or gas-fired power generators.
Also, this time is enough to cover the short-term power outage.
This is the main purpose of the UPS. And not as an alternative power source.

Answer (score 1):

Using the information from the spec. sheets 17 & 18, and 80KW as an example, you would use 80 (28Ah 12v) batteries.  That would be 1KW per battery.  You should be able to draw 80A from the 28Ah battery, for (28 X 60)/80 = 20 minutes.  Taking inefficiencies into account, it might just be 15 minutes.  Obviously, if you want it to last longer or draw more current, you need to add more batteries in parallel.  Keep in mind that UPS are intended to provide power so that systems can continue operating only for a few minutes until main power returns or emergency power is activated, not as a continuous source of power.

EDIT:  In case you need a more realistic answer, you would need about 25 batteries to provide 500A for 1hr, 100 batteries would last you 4 hrs.

Comment: What would you suggest for a longer period? Obviously battery solution is expensive and short.

Comment: Diesel generator, I'm afraid.